# Connect 2 compute modules with networking

Tags: networking, compute-module-3

I've recently acquired 4 Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3's. I plan to develop a Circuit board that has built in networking, to allow both compute modules to talk to one another across a local network.

Since I've never actually worked with networking on a component level, and only on a device level, I'm not sure how I'm going to achieve this.

I'll be having 2 Compute Modules mounted onto a single PCB using SO-DIMM sockets. There will be either 1 or 2 (or none if possible) ethernet controllers between the two boards to create a simple network that will allow me to transfer large amounts of data between the two devices.

I plan to use this setup to drive 3 cameras, 2 in stereo vision, and one for visual purposes, along with a TFT screen to display all the data onto. I wish to design the whole system to be relatively compact, hence having both modules on a single board.

All I need from everyone, is a step in the right direction, either with a project similar to this that has been achieved, or even datasheets of components which provide me with all the info to get started.